# Compute Engine Mysql port not connecting

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine

We are using a debian in GOogle Compute engine and was allowed port tcp:3306 to connect to mysql but we are unable to conect, any workaround ?

Steps:

Created a Health Checks for my service with the name MySQL; 
Pools created a Target for my service named mysql pointing to my region and vm instance; 
Rules created a Forwarding Service pointing to my external IP of my VM instance and port you wish to release.

Regards

Comment: Have you added your external IP of your instance to the authorized networks in your mysql?

Answer (score 2):

I changed the configuration file located at /etc/mysql/my.cnf. In there, I changed the bind-address to 0.0.0.0. After following this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-mysqld-server-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address/), I was able to connect. The Health Checks, Pools and Forwarding rules aren't relevant in this case.